# Windows Server 2012 on EC2 - Clock running too quickly

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012, time

I have a single EC2 Instance for a small project of mine that runs Windows Server 2012 and the clock in windows seems to be gaining a minute every hour or so and it's causing issues in my token based authentication system where I try to validate some timestamps.

I have been running the same server for about 2 months now and have only very recently (last week) started having this issue.

I searched to see if anybody else was having this issue and it does not seem like it.

What are my best course of actions to correct the issue? I was thinking of creating a schedule task to run a time synchronization every 20 minutes or so but that much time drift has to be caused by something else.

Anybody got some clues of what I could do or check to fix the issue?

Comment: What is the time source for the server?

Comment: It currently synchronize with time.windows.com

Comment: [If you've configured NTP properly & Windows is using an external time source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042) it should hold itself in sync. That said, virtual machines generally stink at time-keeping. You could talk to Amazon for suggestions, but you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

There is a SpecialPollInterval value under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpClient, I think this represents seconds between each sync with the NTP server. You could try reducing this?